# Обновление блока на странице языком php

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выглядит скрипт по автоматическому обновлению блока (например, блок <див> или <табле>) на странице, без ее полного обновления.

Comment: Это не php а javascript надо решать.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, код на javascript общий вид или пример.

Comment: http://sevidi.ru/webd/dweb/javapage46.php?id_catalog=13

Answer (score 1):

Здесь поможет, например, плагин jQuery [periodic](https://github.com/tra/periodic) для периодического выполнения ajax-запроса (или [PeriodicalExecuter](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/periodicalExecuter) из Prototype). Другой подход - это работа с [WebSocket API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) из HTML 5.

Например:

```
 <head>
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.periodic.js"></script>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $.periodic({
                 period: 1000,
                 decay: 1.2,
                 max_period: 10000
             }, function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'test.html',
                     context: document.body,
                     success: function (data) {
                         $('#result').html(data);
                     }
                 });
             });
         });
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="result" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы всем, вот нашел хороший пример, который у меня заработал: http://designgala.com/how-to-refresh-div-using-jquery/